# React-Admin translations broken after upgrade to 3.18

Tags: react-admin

Recently upgraded React-Admin in our project from `3.16.2` to `3.18.1` and noticed a bunch of the UI strings changed.

Where it previously said, 'ADD FILTER' or 'CREATE' it now says, 'RA.ACTION.ADD_FILTER' and 'RA.ACTION.CREATE'

[image]

We weren't passing an `i18nProvider` prop to the `<Admin>` component.

After  the strings changed, I thought maybe it was required now, but adding one seems to have no effect.

package.json looks like this

```
"react-admin": "^3.18.1",
"ra-language-english": "^3.18.0",
"ra-i18n-polyglot": "^3.18.0",
```

Did some googling and found one [similar sounding issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5836), but with no solution.
Has anyone else run into anything like this? Thanks.

Comment: You probably have multiple versions of the same package installed. Do you use yarn?

Comment: No, we are using `npm`.

Comment: Installing dependencies with yarn fixed the translation issues, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great suggestion by Gildas to use yarn.

For those wondering, got up and running very quickly by running:

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn
yarn start
```

Some additional helpful info in [the yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/).